# Android - VideoView "access unit is damaged"

Tags: java, android, video

I'm trying to play a video through a `android.wiget.VideoView`. 
This works on a Nexus 4, on 4.4.4, perfectly fine. But when I run it on a MotoX, on 5.1 something happens and I get the following message thousands of times.
I'm thinking this is a problem with the difference between 4.4.4 and 5.1.

Anyone have any thoughts on what could cause this?

`03-18 17:57:50.432: I/AMPEG4ElementaryAssembler(374): access unit is damaged`

Comment: hard to help without code

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a problem with the MediaPlayer using an RTSP stream. I switched to an HTTP live stream which worked much better.